# why my owl carousel items are sorted vertical not horizontal?

Tags: javascript, html, sass, owl-carousel, owl-carousel-2

i want to ask, i have a problem in my owl carousel.

I want to make a center drag slider with the owl carousel, when I've made the code, the items are vertical not horizontal. what's wrong? I've also included a
[Codepen](https://codepen.io/fikryrmdhna/pen/gOrWwvo)

Is the owl carousel not automatic like the slick carousel? If you know, please help me. I need your help, because this is my first time using the owl carousel

**HTML**

```
<div class="slider-news">
  <div class="item">
    <div class="card secondary-card">
       <div class="card-img-top">
          <div class="d-flex" id="tags">
             <div class="tags yellow">Article</div>
             <div class="tags yellow">IT Services</div>
          </div>
       </div>
       <div class="card-body">
          <div class="title">
             <h2>
                3 Tantangan Umum ketika Melakukan IT Outsourcing
             </h2>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  <div class="item">
    <div class="card secondary-card">
       <div class="card-img-top">
          <div class="d-flex" id="tags">
             <div class="tags yellow">Article</div>
             <div class="tags yellow">IT Services</div>
          </div>
       </div>
       <div class="card-body">
          <div class="title">
             <h2>
                3 Tantangan Umum ketika Melakukan IT Outsourcing
             </h2>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  <div class="item">
    <div class="card secondary-card">
       <div class="card-img-top">
          <div class="d-flex" id="tags">
             <div class="tags yellow">Article</div>
             <div class="tags yellow">IT Services</div>
          </div>
       </div>
       <div class="card-body">
          <div class="title">
             <h2>
                3 Tantangan Umum ketika Melakukan IT Outsourcing
             </h2>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  <div class="item">
    <div class="card secondary-card">
       <div class="card-img-top">
          <div class="d-flex" id="tags">
             <div class="tags yellow">Article</div>
             <div class="tags yellow">IT Services</div>
          </div>
       </div>
       <div class="card-body">
          <div class="title">
             <h2>
                3 Tantangan Umum ketika Melakukan IT Outsourcing
             </h2>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  <div class="item">
    <div class="card secondary-card">
       <div class="card-img-top">
          <div class="d-flex" id="tags">
             <div class="tags yellow">Article</div>
             <div class="tags yellow">IT Services</div>
          </div>
       </div>
       <div class="card-body">
          <div class="title">
             <h2>
                3 Tantangan Umum ketika Melakukan IT Outsourcing
             </h2>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**SCSS**

```
.card{
    border: none;
    border-radius: 20px;
&.secondary-card{
        border-radius: 10px;
        overflow: hidden;
        box-shadow: 0px 13px 26px rgba(0,0,0,0.07);

        .card-img-top{
            height: 250px;
            position: relative;
          background-color:#c1c1c1;

            #tags{
                position: absolute;
                top: 20px;
                left: 20px;

                .tags{
                    &:nth-child(1){
                        margin-right: 10px;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        .card-body{
            padding: 40px 30px;
            
            .title{
                h2{
                    position: relative;
                    font-size: 20px;
                    line-height: 27px;

                    &::before{
                        content: '';
                        position: absolute;
                        left: 0;
                        bottom: -10px;
                        height:4px;
                        width:23px;
                        background-color: red;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

.tags{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    padding: 5px 8px;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 13px;

    &.yellow{
        background-color: yellow;
    }

}
```

**JS**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
            $('.slider-news').owlCarousel({
                center: true,
                items: 4,
                loop: false,
                margin: 10,
                nav:false,
                dots:false,
                // responsive: {
                //     600: {
                //         items: 4
                //     }
                // }
            });
        });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hello instead of using the class `.slider-news` try using the `owl-carousel` on your mark up and javascript. I think it has some default styling on the libary. I worked on this library before and I used `owl carousel`. If you want custom style you can use a secondary class on owl carousel.

This is the the link on the [codepen](https://codepen.io/condinoaljoseph/pen/poyPEmM) I edited.

Comment: ohh it's very helpful man. thank you. it cannot use custom class like slick? and why?

Comment: yes you can use may be you can wrap the whole mark up of owl-carousel class into another div and you can override some of its styles using the class.

Comment: @Fikryrmdhna Yes you can use a custom class, but you need to include the `owl-carousel` class as well. No need to wrap it in a new container, just add the `owl-carousel` class to your existing slider container, e.g. `<div class="slider-news owl-carousel">`

Comment: I agreed @FluffyKitten you can also do it like that.